# Is it possible to use variables in the description of a collection or a request in Postman?

Tags: postman

Is it possible to use variables in the description of a request in Postman?

I have created a collection, and want to use a variable in the description.
My main goal is to create json schemas for defining object types, so I thought I would store global variables with the json schema, and reference those types in the description of a request or collection. Is that possible?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can only use the variable syntax to reference those values in specific places. I don't that that currently the description is one of those. More information about variables can be found here. https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/environments_and_globals/variables/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment it isn't possible to use variables in the description of a collection. You can always submit a feature request here:

https://community.getpostman.com/c/feature-requests?order=views

I didn't see a current request for that particular feature, perhaps others would be interested as well.

Comment: Thanks. I’ll add a feature request.